# How to configure CSP in nginx using nonce approach in angular?

Tags: angular, nginx, content-security-policy, nginx-config, nonce

I am developing angular web app. I have implemented CSP(Content Security Policy) with nonce approach using this link- https://dev.to/ferdiesletering/how-to-implement-an-inline-styles-content-security-policy-with-angular-and-nginx-2ke2. Every thing working properly in local setup when added header outside server{} config in nginx file, because CSP header not added in network layer(we can see in Network Tab Console). when  added header inside server config in nginx config file, **getting error related csp that script source not allowed**.

pic for nonce added each style tag,  when added header outside server{} config in nginx
code  and also **CSP header not showing in network tab in console**-[image]

code for this-

```
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter random-csp-nonce $request_id;
  add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'nonce-$request_id'";
server {
  listen 80;
  sendfile on;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   1100;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;
  
  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
  http2_max_field_size 64k;
  http2_max_header_size 512k;
  
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

when added header **inside serve config** and **header will show in network tab** but getting error related to csp

```
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter random-csp-nonce $request_id;

server {
  listen 80;
  sendfile on;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   1100;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;
  
  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

 //added header here  
 add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'nonce-$request_id'"; 
  http2_max_field_size 64k;
  http2_max_header_size 512k;
  
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

**Error pic(blocking script execution)**-[image]

**Network tab** pic-[image]

Also **nonce value not added for style tag** also- [image]

Please help me how to resolve this and implement proper CSP in angular

Comment: Suggest any alternate way to achieve CSP in angular

Comment: Seems that "For security reasons, the nonce content attribute is hidden (an empty string will be returned)." (see [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/nonce#accessing_nonces_and_nonce_hiding)). You can use the `nonce` property to access nonces (i.e. select the `<style>` element in dev tools, then write in the console `$0.nonce`).

Answer (score 1):

The `server` is not a tag but a *configuration level*, or *context*. The reason why you didn't get a CSP header with your first configuration is obvious and documented by the `add_header` directive [documentation](http://nginx.org/r/add_header):

> These directives are inherited from the previous configuration level **if and only if** there are no `add_header` directives defined on the current level.

I'm not sure why your `style` tag nonces does not get replaced in your second configuration (or it looks like they are replaced with an empty strings?), however your first step should be moving those `sub_filter` directives to the server configuration level (or maybe even to the location level) since you definitely didn't want them to have global effect on all your hosted vhosts.

Comment: Hi Ivan Shatsky, I have tried adding subfilter inside server configuration, but getting same error

Comment: Sorry, adding `sub_filter` to server level or _moving_ `sub_filter` from http level to server level? I don't have an explanation why you get your nonces string being replaced with your first config and didn't get the same with the second one, however there should be an explanation. Can you re-check your first configuration once more?